# CDI Inject @RequestScoped bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, inject

I have a JAR File which contains a `RequestScoped` Bean. (A Class annotated as `@RequestScoped`).

I have another Web Services project (which I build as a WAR File). The above JAR file is present in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the WAR file.

I am trying to `@Inject` the `@RequestScoped` Class into one of the classes in the Web Service Project.

I am getting a

```
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException
```

Both the projects have the JAR file and the WAR file contain an empty `beans.xml`.
I have been on this problem for a couple of days now. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have used the `RequestScoped`-annotation from the wrong Java-package? Correct would be `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`.